# Why this class have to be case class?

Tags: scala, class, instantiation, case-class

This class:

```
class Id[A](value: A) {
 def map[B](f: A => B): Id[B] = Id(f(value))
 def flatMap[B](f: A => Id[B]): Id[B] = f(value)
}
```

got error:"not found value Id" at line 2

it's fine if the class is a case class:

```
case class Id[A](value: A) {
```

I don't know why this class have to be case class,Thanks!

Comment: If it is not a case class you would need to write `new Id(f(value))`  to create a new instance. For case classes the `new` keyword is not necessary

Comment: @HaraldGliebe is correct, except in Scala 3 where the need for `new` has been relaxed and your code [compiles and runs](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/C3jcCzq4T1ODKL2CPULXkQ) without error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68493548/why-this-class-have-to-be-case-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be a `case class` per se. It just needs to have a corresponding `apply` on its companion object to create a new instance (which `case` classes automatically do for you).

If you really don't want it to be a `case class` for whatever reason, you can define the companion `apply` yourself like so:

```
class Id[A](value: A) {
 def map[B](f: A => B): Id[B] = Id(f(value))
 def flatMap[B](f: A => Id[B]): Id[B] = f(value)
}
object Id {
  def apply[A](value: A) = new Id(value)
}
```

Alternatively, as others have pointer out, you can explicitly instantiate `Id` with the `new` keyword:

```
class Id[A](value: A) {
 def map[B](f: A => B): Id[B] = new Id(f(value))
 def flatMap[B](f: A => Id[B]): Id[B] = f(value)
}
```